# How do I convert Collection of [UILabel] to string text to display on ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to display the same information on a collection of `[UILabel]`, but I am getting this error,

> Value of type '`[UILabel]?`' has no member 'text'

I am getting the specific error on this line in my code.

```
storagetypelabel.text = "\(booking.storageType.uppercased()) STORAGE"
```

Would love some input on how to alter the way my property.text label is typed.

Since I hooked up multiple `UILabel` to one `[UILabel]` collection, when I call the `[UILabel]` property, I should be able to display the same information for all the connected labels in the collection right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is a property of a single `UILabel` not an array , To set the text for all labels use

```
let str = "\(booking.storageType.uppercased()) STORAGE"
storagetypelabel.forEach { $0.text = str }
```

Comment: Awesome! this worked like a charm! I am quite new to closures so I don't fully understand what is going on in this line of code.  So the forEach is called to say that forEach storagetypelabel, call the $0 (first index) and set the text to it?

Comment: `forEach` is a new way of doing `for` loop , `$0` represents each element inside that array in that case it's a `UILabel` so you can append `.text` to it and assign it like any other single outlet label